# Symfony 2 - Doctrine ORM Update query not working

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying to update a mysql table with following query using Doctrine. But the table is not get updated. Also below code didnt throw any error. I am totally confused. If i run the query, taken from getDQL() method, in mysql directly it showing 0 rows updated becuase of inproper qoutes. it is working after placed proper qoutes for values in the query. Need help to solve this puzzle.

Since i am new to doctrine, i will use the examples give in querybuilder class file.

```
    $support = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->update('gcns', 'g')
                    ->set("g.isActive", "0")
                    ->andWhere("g.issn='".$issn."'");
```

Comment: is it your only code ? did you execute it after ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you ever execute the query or are you just building it? You should have something along these lines to execute it:

```
$support->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

> If i run the query, taken from getDQL() method, in mysql directly it showing 0 rows updated becuase of inproper qoutes.

`getDQL()` returns DQL not SQL, so it will have improper quotesif you try to run it directly inside MySQL, but that's expected.

You shouldn't concatenate `$issn` into your query. You should use parameters instead:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()

$support = $qb->update('gcns', 'g')
   ->set('g.isActive', '0')
   ->andWhere( $qb->expr()->eq('g.issn', ':issn') )
   ->setParameter( 'issn', $issn )
   ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult()
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Anyhow i solved it by myself.

Comment: @RosiEvangelin Okay, just make sure that you do remove the concatenated string. Doing `"g.issn='".$issn."'"` instead of using a parameter is bad for both security and performance reasons.